# How to convert a list of Torch tensor with grad to tensor

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, heatmap, tensor, face-alignment

I have a variable called pts which is shaped [batch, ch, h, w]. This is a heatmap and I want to convert it to 2nd co-ordinates. The goal is, pts_o = heatmap_to_pts(pts) where pts_o will be [batch, ch, 2]. I have wrote this function so far,

```
def heatmap_to_pts(self, pts):  <- pts [batch, 68, 128, 128]
    
    pt_num = []
    
    for i in range(len(pts)):
        
        pt = pts[i]
        if type(pt) == torch.Tensor:

            d = torch.tensor(128)                                                   * get the   
            m = pt.view(68, -1).argmax(1)                                           * indices
            indices = torch.cat(((m / d).view(-1, 1), (m % d).view(-1, 1)), dim=1)  * from heatmaps
        
            pt_num.append(indices.type(torch.DoubleTensor) )   <- store the indices in a list

    b = torch.Tensor(68, 2)                   * trying to convert
    c = torch.cat(pt_num, out=b) *error*      * a list of tensors with grad
    c = c.reshape(68,2)                       * to a tensor like [batch, 68, 2]

    return c
```

The error says "cat(): functions with out=... arguments don't support automatic differentiation, but one of the arguments requires grad.". It's unable to do the operations because tensors in pt_num requires grad".

How can I convert that list to a tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says,

> cat(): functions with out=... arguments don't support automatic differentiation, but one of the arguments requires grad.

What that means is that the output of functions such as `torch.cat()` which as an `out=` kwarg cannot be used as input to the autograd engine (which performs automatic differentiation).

The reason is that the tensors (in your Python list `pt_num`) have different values for the `requires_grad` attribute, i.e., some tensors have `requires_grad=True` while some of them have `requires_grad=False`.

In your code, the following line is (logically) troublesome:

```
c = torch.cat(pt_num, out=b)
```

The return value of `torch.cat()`, irrespective of whether you use `out=` kwarg or not, is the concatenation of tensors along the mentioned dimension.

So, the tensor `c` is already the concatenated version of individual tensors in `pt_num`. Using `out=b` redundant. Thus, you can simply get rid of the `out=b` and everything should be fine.

```
c = torch.cat(pt_num)
```